# Is a file opened in place of stderr buffered?

Tags: c, linux

On Linux, the `stdout` (fd 1) output stream is buffered and `stderr` (fd 2) is not.

Say I do something like this:

```
int main() {
    close(2);
    open( "newfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600 );
    fprintf(stderr, "This is in the text file!");
    fflush(stderr);  //does this do anything? is it needed?
    return 0;
}
```

If I remember correctly, `open` uses the lowest available file descriptor, which should be 2 (used to be stderr before the `close` statement). Since `stderr` is not buffered, will `newfile.txt` not be buffered as well? Or does it not matter that fd 2 used to be used for `stderr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually do anything with `stderr` so it's status and buffering is unchanged. All you do is change the underlying file descriptor (***if*** the `open` call doesn't fail of course).

---

The same behavior can be had by saving the returned file descriptor from `open` and using [`dup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), or `dup2` if you don't close the old file descriptor. I would actually recommend using `dup2` instead, as it's more explicit and easier to follow what's happening:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd = open( "newfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600 );
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (dup2(STDERR_FILENO, fd) == -1) {
        perror("dup2");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "This is in the text file!");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the call to fflush

Answer (score -1):

<s>I think your code will most likely seg fault since `fflush()` expects a `FILE*` not Unix file descriptor.</s>

`fprintf()` buffers the output.  It doesn't know any different since the file descriptor hasn't changed as far as it is concerned, so `fflush()` is still needed.

Comment: Sorry about the fflush call, I edited it and fixed it